# Create Array of Hashes from Nokogiri nodeset with .name as Key and .text as value

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm stuck, been pounding my head on this one.. I want an array of hashes from this nodeset.

I've got this nodeset from Nokogiri.

```
joe = <sku>4A</sku>
<quantity type="integer">6</quantity>
<sku>5B</sku>
<quantity type="integer">2</quantity>
```

And what I want is this:

```
[{"sku"=> "4A", "quantity"=> 6}, {"sku"=> "5B", "quantity"=> 2}]
```

I've tried:

```
Hash[*joe]
```

But that gives me:

```
{"<sku>4A</sku>"=> "<quantity type="integer">6</quantity>"}
```

I've tried map:

```
Hash[joe.map {|x| [x.name,x.text]}]
```

And that is ALMOST it, but it stops after the first 2..

```
{"sku"=>"4A", "quantity"=>"6"}
```

Where did I go astray?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your example nodeset didn't come from Nokogiri, as it doesn't *EVER* output information like that. If that's supposed to be input XML, it's not valid. What code did you write to solve this problem? We help you fix your code, we don't write it for you, so show us your minimal code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
key = nil
joe.each_with_object([]) do |child, akku|
  if key.nil?
    key = child.text
  else
    akku << {'sku' => key, 'quantity' => child.text.to_i}
    key = nil
  end
end
```

Or (which of course loops quite more than needed)

```
values = joe.map(&:text)
skus = values.select.each_with_index { |item, index| index.even? }
quantites = values.select.each_with_index { |item, index| index.odd? }
result = skus.zip(quantites).each_with_object([]) do |(sku, quantity), akku|
  akku << {'sku' => sku, 'quantity' => quantity.to_i}
end
```

Comment: Well, i assume joe is the node set that we iterate?. The XML format is not ideal in that it has information which belongs together (SKU/Quantity) on the same level but in different XML elements. It'd be easier if those were attributes of the same element. Or those elements are grouped together inside another XML element. This represents some shopping basket or order information, i guess?

Comment: Back at it today!! wahoo.. but shoot your answer didn't work.. Came back with an empty array.. But got me thinking.. keep pushing!!

Comment: Can you post a full sample? XML + How you access it through Nokogiri.